# Shadows from shadow caster 2D are infinite in length

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Shadow Caster 2D to cast shadows from my sprites but the shadows are infinite in length. This does make sense but not in what I am trying to do where I want to cast a shadow from the sun.

[image]

I would ideally like the shadow of the boat to end where that red line is.
Does anyone know if this is possible with Shadow Caster 2D.

Thanks

Comment: If who ever down votes would like to explain why they have that would be useful

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing as well, use URP 2D lighting to generate some shadow with "Heights", and I end up with nothing.
The closest thing I have found is from this unity post, from Unity employee

> Blockquote
> This is actually something I wanted to do, but I'm hesitant to add something official only because the shadows need to be reworked. If you wanted to make the changes yourself, I can try and give you some advice on how to do this.

you can find the full post here
https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-lighting-shadows.826584/

so there are two options left, write my own shader some logical scripts, or find an asset.
There's an asset called smart lighting 2D is very close to what I was looking for, but not perfect, you can find the asset here. The latest update starts supporting the shadow height.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/smart-lighting-2d-112535

Let's see how or when Unity can make some more shadow features for the 2D lighting

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would provide an update to this for anyone who finds/faces this issue, as the problem drove me crazy.  I managed to find an older article and used the excellent work they had done on an older version of the URP pipeline to implement it well enough for the current version to (semi)solve this issue (though it raises another issue, which is that the geometry of the shadow doesn't seem to match the shadowcaster2d shape).  Anyways, see the link for an outline of the edits required to implement a shadow length slider/modifier to your (non-global) light source, as well as the shadowcaster2d, that will let you alter the length of the shadows for your lightsource, as well as for each individual shadowcaster2d.  Requires:  Unity, 2D project, URP pipeline, 2D light-source (non-global), shadowcaster2d.

Scroll to the bottom of the forum for my posts ("badcceb")
https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-lighting-shadows.826584/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using the ShadowCaster2D from URP, if so, you could edit the code, and try and change the geometry of the shadow. There doesn't seem to be any way to do it, other than that.

1. [ShadowCaster2D](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Graphics/blob/d0473769091ff202422ad13b7b764c7b6a7ef0be/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Runtime/2D/ShadowCaster2D.cs)
2. [Shadow geometry code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Graphics/blob/d0473769091ff202422ad13b7b764c7b6a7ef0be/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Runtime/2D/Shadows/ShadowUtility.cs)